# How can I make a mirror which reflects only chosen things?

Tags: animation, mirror

I'm making an animation and I would like to make a mirror which reflects only things which I choose. To be more specific, two characters are going to stand in front of the mirror, but there would be reflection of just one of them, like on this picture below:

[image]

Is there an option to make it in Blender?

Comment: Maybe you can build shaders that don have specular bounces, but the easier way is to take advantage of the compositor. Have you tried that?

Comment: To be honest, I have not tried anything, it's difficult to try while being a noob in compositor :/

Comment: Are you using cycles or eevee?

Comment: I'm using cycles. @ChristopherBennett

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this node setup for the material of the object you don't want reflected (in this case the red object). You can also use the "Is Reflection Ray" output of the light path node as a mix factor:

[image: Reflect]

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to achieve! It works - thank you so much :)

Comment: If animated, you can go a step further with a math>subtract from `-1 to 1` between the lightpath and factor to hide/reveal objects, makes an interesting effect in some cases....

Comment: Is the test Reflection Ray or Glossy Ray?

Answer (score 10):

### Composite view layers

You can take advantage of view layers and compositing. It's very flexible and collection-driven.

Create a collection with the objects that you don't want to appear in the mirror (s_vampire in this case).

Create two view layer and in one Disable the collection you created before: one with everything enabled called for example **ref**

[image]

And one othe called for example **n vis** with the collection disabled.

[image]

Now, just use cryptomatte layer to pick the mirror plane as a mask in the compositor:

[image]

The scene will be rendered 2 times and the mirror will show only the scene where the collection with s_vampire object is disabled. This is the result.

[image]

You can download the file here to explore the scene:

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice, it looks good. Thank you.